# gettimeofday - explanation of the exact struct timeval fields' meaning

Tags: c, gettimeofday

I'm trying to write a simple function in C that would calculate the difference between two moments in nanoseconds. To do this, I thought of using the function `gettimeofday`, which updates the given struct timeval's fields.

As the man page said, the struct timeval's fields are:

```
time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */  
suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
```

My question is as follows:

Is the `tv_usec` field is the WHOLE TIME passed since the EPOCH in microseconds, or is it just the remain of the time in microseconds?

For example, if the time passed is 100 seconds and 25 microseconds, will the `tv_usec` field have the value '25' or the value '100000025'?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW, `gettimeofday` only provides microsecond resolution, and is obsolete in POSIX.1-2008, so you should use `clock_gettime` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the remainder.

> This is the rest of the elapsed time (a fraction of a second), represented as the number of microseconds. It is always less than one million.

Comment: Just FYI: a signed 64 bit number (`long long` must be at least this long) could represent almost 300,000 years from the epoch, measured in microseconds.

Comment: A 32 bit integer can only represent a little more than 71 minutes as microseconds.